# How to stop Firebug from jumping in the source code all the time

Tags: firefox, javascript, web-development, firebug

If a JavaScript is changing something (e.g. a style), Firebug jumps to the position in the source code where the change happened. The problem is that I want to analyze a certain part of the source code but every time I scroll to a certain location it jumps right back to another location. So I cannot analyze the source code with Firebug. Deactivating JavaScript is not an option because in most cases the pages looks completely different.

Is there a switch or setting for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a setting in Firebug in the HTML drop-down menu called, "Scroll to changes." I'm guessing this may be what you want.

(yes, I know this is my 2nd answer, but I just found this setting)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but I found this setting:

```
    extensions.firebug.scrollToMutations
```

on this page: https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php?title=HTML_Panel&oldid=8220

It says this setting, "Toggles scrolling to changes to the DOM structure inside the Node View."